# The amount of ring homomorphisms from $Z_{12}$ to $Z_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I know that if $\phi$ is a homomorphism, $1$ must get sent to an element that has order that divides $12$, so our options for $\phi(1)$ are $2,4,6,0$ but we also need $\phi(1)^2=\phi(1^2)=\phi(1)$ and since $2^2\ne 2, 4^2\ne 4, 6^2\ne 6$. So our only option for $\phi(1)$ is $0$. So there is only one homomorphism from $Z_{12}$ to $Z_8$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$.